# Why a unknown repository is in my pinned section in GitHub?

Tags: github

I didn't have or contributed in a repository and it's not in my repositories on my profile.
But when I want to **PIN** a repo, it shows me a repo I have not ever seen.
What's the problem? How can I delete it from my list?

[image]

Comment: You've never interacted with this repository?  Did you check this or are you relying on memory?  It's possible that the repository was renamed.  Is it a fork of one of your repositories?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I have interacted with this but It's not important and I don't want it anymore. What can I do?